# React: removing a css className breaks transition

Tags: reactjs, css-transitions

I have a ajax transition which is applyed to a DOM element by setting the className "fetching" in the `render()`-Method whenever the Component fetches data from the server. After `fetch()` returns, I let that className be removed so the Component can transition back to its original appearance.

It works like this:

```js
fetchStuff() {
    this.setState({fetching: true})
    fetch(stuff)
    .then(answer => {
       // do stuff with the answer
       this.setState({fetching: false})
    )
}

// and then ...
render() {
    let {fetching} = this.state
    return <div className={'my-component' + (fetching ? ' fetching' : '')}></div>
 }
```

```css
.my-component {
  transition: all .3s;
  opacity: 1;
 }

.my-component.fetching {
  opacity: 0;
 }
```

The start transition works fine! But when React removes the "fetching" className, the Component jumps to its original appearance without transition.

What can I do?
Thanks for your help :)

### UPDATE:

Somehow this problem occurs more often in Chrome than in Firefox.

### UPDATE 2:

Preventing unnecessary rerenders by using `shouldComponentUpdate()` on the parent Component made it better but still the transition sometimes skips or is way too fast. But sometimes it is now smooth as it should be.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle or codepen?

Comment: Unfortunately, my project is too big to share it :/ The above is just a simple abstraction of the situation which would probably work fine on its own. But I have a lot of nested Components which get updated. Reducing the updates with `shouldComponentUpdate` brings some benefit. So I guess it has something to do with the enormous amount of `render()` calls.

Comment: @caffinatedmonkey Did you have problems like this in the past with React + css transitions?

Comment: It might be caused by [Reconciliation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html). Try adding a `key`.

Comment: hmmm... had them already. Maybe it is just an implementation/performance issue of the browser: there is fetching + a lot of function calls (React) + large planes which get rerendered (css+DOM) async... Maybe my machine or the browsers are not ready for so much stuff going on at the same time...